# How can I fix this sign up system?

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I have made a sign up system using HTML, CSS and PHP.
The logic error is that any time I attempt to login it always makes error=empty input even though I have entered something.

All code is below

**HTML**

```
<?php
    include_once 'header.php';
    
?>
<head>
    <style>
        input{
            background-color:#c5d5f0;
            font-family: 'Courier New';
            
        }
        
        #subButton{
            background-color: #304ca6;
            color: #ed951a;
            font-family: 'Courier New';
            position: relative;
            left: -40px;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section style="color:#304ca6; text-align:center; ">
        <!-- this is title message -->
        <strong><p style="font-family: 'Courier New'; font-size:20px;">Sign up to Blue Cow</p></strong>
        <!-- this links to a php file containing the sign up functions we have to run on the data once submitted -->
        <form method="post" action="includes/signup.inc.php">
            <label for="username" style="position: relative; left:-40px;">Username:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter a username" style="position:relative; left:-35px; width:300px;"><br>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <label for="password" style="position: relative; left:-40px;">Password:</label><br>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter a password" style="position:relative; left:-35px; width:300px;"><br>
            </p>
            <label for="password" style="position: relative; left:-40px;">Password Repeat:</label><br>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="passwordRepeat" placeholder="Enter a password" style="position:relative; left:-35px; width:300px;"><br>
            <p></p>
            <input type="submit" id="subButton" name="submit" value ="Sign Up">
            
        </form>
    </section>
    
</body>
```

I link it to another file called signup.inc.php
The contents of that is below

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $passwordRepeat = $_POST["passwordRepeat"];
    
    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    require_once 'functions.inc.php';
    #if it is anything besides false run an error
    if (emptyInputSignup($username, $password, $passwordRepeat) !== false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=emptyinput");
        exit();
    }
    
    if (invalidUsername($username) !== false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=invalidusername");
        exit();
    }
    
    if (passwordMatch($password, $passwordRepeat) !== false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=passworddontmatch");
        exit();
    }
    
    if (usernameExists($conn, $username) !== false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=usernametaken");
        exit();
        
    }
    
    if (passwordValid($password) !== false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=passwordisnotvalid");
        exit();
    }
    
    createUser($conn, $username, $password);
    
}

else{
    header("location: ../signup.php");
}
```

I also made a separate file for the functions called function.inc.php.
Here is the code for that.

```
<?php
#since this file contains solely PHP there is no need for the closing tag
#by convention it is better to check if something fails first then succeeds
function emptyInputSignup($username, $password, $passwordRepeat){
    $result;
    if (empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return result;
}




function invalidUsername($username){
    $result = Null;
    #if there is a mistake
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

function passwordMatch($password, $passwordRepeat){
    $result = Null;
    #if there has been a mistake
    if ($password !== $passwordRepeat){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

function usernameExists($conn, $username){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    #we have created a prepared statement to prevent SQL injections
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    $result = Null;
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }
    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    
    $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result();
    
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)){ 
        return $row;        
        
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
        return $result;
    }
    
}

function passwordValid($password){
    $result = Null;
    #if there is a mistake
    if (strlen($password) <= 5 && !preg_match("~[0-9]+~", $password)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

function createUser($conn, $username, $password){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
    #we have created a prepared statement to prevent SQL injections
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    #this checks if the statement is feasible
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }
    #returns hash of a password
    #this inbuilt function is constantly updated
    $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);   
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $hashedPassword);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    header("location: ../signup.php?error=none");
    exit;   
}
```

Comment: Can you please turn this into [MCVE]? This is too much code. Which part are we meant to look at?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a dollar sign before the result variable in the return statement:

```
return result;
```

This should be

```
return $result;
```

Hopefully this helps!

### Tip

I personally always use the following code when I am trying to find where I made a mistake in my script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

These lines of PHP tell your server to echo all errors including additional information about the error (e.g. on line X).

Comment: should i put that code at the beginning of each script?

Comment: @Miscellaneous, excuse me for my late respond. No you should not. Only at the beginning of scripts you're debugging. Remove it afterwards (otherwise your users will see unnecessary error messages).